# Flutter - How to make a circular button inside bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

I want to make a circular button in the middle of my navigation bar similar to youtube.

this is my code

```
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            label: 'Search',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('xxx');
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.grey,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            label: 'Groceries',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
```

[image]

This is the end result I want.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change the `BorderRadius.circular()` to a higher number? Or maybe try `BorderRadius.All()` with a high number.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: You can change your shape to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/CircleBorder-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     Icon(
        Icons.add_circle_outline,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
       ),
```

You can use flutter built in icon.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
          Container(
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('xxx');
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                primary: Colors.grey,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```